# How to plot multiple Time Series Plots in R

Tags: r, time-series

I want to put multiple Time series plots on the same plot in R. I know we can usually do something like `ts.plot(model1, model2, model3, col = 1:3)`. However, I now have 54 models. Is there an elegant way to this or i just plot them manually?

I think it will be something like:

```
for (i in 1:54){
ts.plot(model[i], model[i+1])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `do.call` after getting all the plots in a list with `mget`.

```
do.call(ts.plot, mget(paste0("model", 1:54)))
```